# qUnit vs Selenium for testing non-pure Javascript functions

Tags: jquery, testing, selenium, qunit

I have a case where all my JavaScript functions are non-pure
all of functions output are side effects to some HTML elements (or ajax calls) using jQuery
Also most of my code is inside anonymous functions and triggered by User events

Could Selenium completely replace qUnit in this case ??

Comment: Zombie could completely replace qUnit in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems subjective to me. It *could* replace qUnit, but you're doing an integration test with Selenium rather than a unit test (with QUnit). These are two very different kinds of tests. It sounds like the JavaScript you want to test is not separated from the DOM elements and is therefore difficult to unit test. You should refactor your code to allow unit testing, but if that's too much effort then use an integration test (Selenium would work for that).

In an ideal world you would be using both unit and integration tests.